# How do I know who uses my API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api

Is there any software I can install that will give me information about my API usage in Rails? I see some API management services but they are all VERY expensive and very complex. I want something to give me basic information about my API.

Also, log analysis seems a way to go. However, I'd like to know if this is the solution that is most used by companies right now. They must use something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if your users already have API key, you can track the activity by following code:

```
#applications_controller.rb (controller)
after_filter :track_api_usage

private

def track_api_usage
  current_user.api_tracking(params) if params[:api_key]
end


#user.rb (model)
has_many :trackings

def api_tracking(params)
  trackings.create(self.id, params)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not add an API key which users of your api need to register for, like google maps. Make it as easy as possible otherwise they wont use your api. Having a key for your API means you can prevent usage abuse of your API. I.e. if there is too much traffic from a registered address then you can cut them off.

Comment: That's not exactly what I asked. I have the API key for each user. I just want a way to keep track of what the user is doing with his API key.